Directing Domain to GoDaddy website hosting
I haven't done this before.  The domain is registered at TCA and the hosting is at GoDaddy.
According to GoDaddy's documentation I have updated the name servers at TCA to

ns41.domaincontrol.com
ns42.domaincontrol.com

I know it will take a while to percolate through.  Is that all I need to do?
This has a few solutions like changing Nameservers and C record. I have done what GoDaddy told me to do.  What I am asking is that all I have to do?
Update
I see that there are zone records at TCA



Record type
Record name
Destination




SOA
example.com
ns1.partnerconsole.net.


A
example.com
was still TCA IPaddress, have changed it to GoDaddy


A
www
TCA IPAdress, do I change this too


NS
example.com
was still TCA name server, changed it to GoDaddy




By changing the nameservers, all you have technically done is to change the server where DNS is hosted.
Generally this is enough if you haven't changed any DNS settings, as one would expect that the default settings are what you need for hosting on that server.
Now that you have changed the nameservers, nothing you do in DNS at TCA will make any difference, they aren't the current records.

That makes sense. I had reversed my changes and just put in A records for the url and www.  Thats working fine.  However, ftp still doesnt work.  - Cant find hostname.  So I am thinking that this is the wrong way to do it.  Qs: if I change the nameservers under settings, they dont reflect in the zone records.  So, do I have to change the NS records in the zone records as well?

@RohitGupta - where are you asking about changing the NS records?  You shouldn't have to touch anything at godaddy unless you want some a custom record.  If the hostname isn't working for FTP, have you tried using the IP address?
